# @org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped invokes @PostConstruct on unload of an already destroyed view

Tags: jsf, omnifaces, view-scope, postconstruct

I have a problem working with **@org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped** and multiple tabs:

I have a link in TestPage.xhtml that opens another page (ShowValuePage.xhtml) with a request parameter "someValue". If I open this link 10 times in a new tab and navigate away in the first opened tab, **PostConstruct will be called again instead of just navigating away.**

Same happens if I navigate back from ShowValuePage to TestPage multiple times. (To test this, we must click the links "Show Value" and "Home" multiple times).

This only happens if more tabs are opened than defined in the web.xml values "numberOfLogicalViews" and "numberOfViewsInSession".

I've set up a small project that shows this problem. The exact description of the procedure can be found in the readme.txt.

[Project on github](https://github.com/wilhei/jsfMultipleTabs)

Is there a workaround for this?

Thank you and best regards

Heinrich

PS: I reported it as a [bug on Omnifaces](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/483), but since a week I didn't get an answer.

Comment: So it works with the plain jsf/cdi ViewScoped annotation?

Comment: For me this behaviour is sort of as expected, Tab != View. Opening the same page in multiple tabs is the same as reloading the same page in one tab and then going back x times (10 in your case). Are you btw taking some course? 3 similar/identical/related question by different people in 1 week. Deltaspike windowscoped is better for you in this case

Comment: The jsf/cdi Viewscoped annotaion didn't work for us. With the javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped we had the problem, that if we work in multiple tabs and close one groupConversationScope in the first tab, then all viewScopes in the second Tab were also closed.

Comment: No, I open a Link multiple times, that opens another page. Then I navigate from the first openend tab to another page by clicking a link. This should not reload the page, this should naviagte, without reloading the current page.

Answer (score 2):

It's fixed in OmniFaces 2.7.1 and 3.3.

The symptoms were caused by an explicit redirect which was initially in place in order to trigger any authentication framework which remembers the "last restricted request" to remember the correct request in case the session is expired. This has been fixed by sending the redirect only and only if the session is actually new.